# How many zeros can holomorphic ftn f have, when k-th derivative of f is bounded away from zero.

Tags: complex-analysis

f is holomorphic function from C to C
, | k-th derivative of f | > 1 on whole C

Then, how can we bound the number of zeros of f in terms of k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|f^{(k)}|>1$ on $C$, then $f^{(k)}$ is an entire function without zeroes and

$|\frac{1}{f^{(k)}}|<1$ on $C$.

Now use Liouville.